# groupingBy on stream<String[]>

Tags: java-stream

I have a situation where i have to generate a Map from List

I have a List  as below

```
List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
li.add("A:abc");
li.add("B:xyz");
li.add("C:mno");
li.add("B:bbb");
li.add("A:aaa");
li.add("C:xxx");
```

I want to generate a Map from this as below
`Map<String, String[]>` or `Map<String, List<String>>`

I wrote the below lambda expression

```
li.stream().map(i->i.split(":")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i->i[0]));
```

but the resultant map is `Map<String, List<String[]>>` , which is not expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this.

- stream the list
- split the string.
- `groupingBy` on first element of array from split
- the `mapping` to put the second element from array in the list.

```
List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
li.add("A:abc");
li.add("B:xyz");
li.add("C:mno");
li.add("B:bbb");
li.add("A:aaa");
li.add("C:xxx");

Map<String, List<String>> map =
        li.stream().map(str -> str.split(":"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
                        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1],
                                Collectors.toList())));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
A=[abc, aaa]
B=[xyz, bbb]
C=[mno, xxx]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @WJS is perfect, however, if you want to get a `Map<String, String[]>` like you asked in the question, you might consider extending it using `Collectors.collectingAndThen` and `List#toArray`

```java
Map<String, String[]> result = li.stream()
                                 .map(x -> x.split(":"))
                                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                     x -> x[0], 
                                     Collectors.mapping(
                                         x -> x[1], 
                                         Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                             Collectors.toList(),
                                             x -> x.toArray(String[]::new)
                                         )
                                     )
                                 ));
```

```
result.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " : " + Arrays.toString(value)));
```

Prints the expected result

```
A : [abc, aaa]
B : [xyz, bbb]
C : [mno, xxx]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to generate a Map from this as below `Map<String, String[]>` or
> `Map<String, List<String>>`

You do not need to call `.map`; just collect the stream using `Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split(":")[0])`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
        li.add("A:abc");
        li.add("B:xyz");
        li.add("C:mno");
        li.add("B:bbb");
        li.add("A:aaa");
        li.add("C:xxx");

        Map<String, List<String>> map = 
                li.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split(":")[0]));

        map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A=[A:abc, A:aaa]
B=[B:xyz, B:bbb]
C=[C:mno, C:xxx]
```

However, if you are expecting a result like

```
A=[abc, aaa]
B=[xyz, bbb]
C=[mno, xxx]
```

you can call `.map` as you are doing and then group by the first element of the array, obtained as a result of splitting, mapping against the list of the second element of the array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
        li.add("A:abc");
        li.add("B:xyz");
        li.add("C:mno");
        li.add("B:bbb");
        li.add("A:aaa");
        li.add("C:xxx");

        Map<String, List<String>> map = 
                li.stream()
                    .map(s -> s.split(":"))
                    .collect(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(
                                    arr -> arr[0], Collectors.mapping(
                                                        arr -> arr[1], Collectors.toList()
                                                    )
                                )
                            );

        map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Immensely helpful solution to use `groupingBy + mapping`. I ended up using it in my code